# Changing SAS ODS contentitem for PROC SQL SELECT statement

Tags: html, sql, sas

When in SAS creating ODS output to a HTML file, it is also possible to create table of contents with "CONTENTS" and "FRAME" options:

```
ODS HTML PATH="C:\Path\" (url=none)
         BODY="body.html"
         CONTENTS="contents.html"
         FRAME="frame.html";
...
(create ODS output here)
...
ODS HTML CLOSE;
```

The default output is quite generic and, therefore, it is better to change the contentproclabel:

```
ods proclabel 'Label for the analysis';
```

This works in all of the cases.

It would also nice to change the contentitem. With PROC GCHART it works as follows:

```
proc gchart data=mydata;
block dataitem / description="Description of the graph";
RUN;
```

But how to change the contentitem when creating PROC SQL SELECT statement? 
With

```
ods proclabel 'Summary of analysis variables';
```

I can change the contentproclable in number list, but how to change the contentitem which by default is always "Query Results" in "PROC SQL; SELECT ... FROM table; QUIT;" statements?

Below is an example table of contents output from the above examples:

```
Table of Contents 
1. Label for the analysis
   ·Description of the graph 
2. Summary of analysis variables
   ·Query Results
```

There you can see the

```
   ·Query Results
```

row whose contentitem I would like to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the `BASE.SQL` template.  Bari Lawhorn shows how to do that in his paper, [Let's Give them Something to TOC About](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/252-2011.pdf) on page 7.

An excerpt, modified slightly, appropriate for your specific question:

```
proc template; 
edit base.sql; 
  mvar sqlcl;   *This defines &sqlcl. as a macro variable that stores your value;
  contents_label=SQLcl;   *uses &sqlcl;
end; 
run; 

%let sqlcl=Summary of analysis variables;

proc sql;
  select * from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Comment: In addition, I was defining the contents_label of a proc sql select query inside a macro, and therefore, I had to define the contents_label variable global in order it to work: %macro test(); %global sqlcl; ... %mend;